# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.so

Tags: scikit-learn, julia, cross-validation, intel-mkl

I'm trying to use train_test_split in Julia 1.0.5 with this code:

```
using ScikitLearn
using ScikitLearn.CrossValidation: train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2019)
```

And I got this error:

```
INTEL MKL ERROR: /home/denis/.julia/conda/3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mkl/../../../libmkl_core.so: неверный заголовок ELF.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_core.so.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

How can I solve this problem?

OS Ubuntu 18.02, Julia 1.0.5.